# texture doesnt appear when loading OpenGl texture using SOIL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to add a texture to my square displayed on the screen, but after i've done all the code the square is still white, and I cant figure out what's wrong, I think I might be missing something after I've loaded the texture.

this is the code I use for creating the texture:

```
void textureManager::createTexture(const char* fileName) {
    GLuint textureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(fileName, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
    if (0 == textureID) {
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}
```

And I call this function after the vertex and index buffer data, before the shaders compile

this is my vertex and fragment shader code:

```
#version 430
in layout(location = 0) vec2 position;
in layout(location = 1) vec2 texCoord;
out vec2 vertex_texCoord;
void main()
{
     gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
     vertex_texCoord = texCoord;
}


#version 430
out vec4 fragmentColor;
in vec2 vertex_texCoord;
uniform sampler2d textureSampler;
void main()
{
    fragmentColor = texture(textureSampler, vertex_texCoord);
}
```

can someone help me please

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  You could be missing a `glUniform()` call for all we know.

Answer (score 0):

Your shaders look fine. You are making the GLuint id too. Hm, are you sending it to the shader in your drawcall?

It should look something like this:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); //texture uniform
```

and be called when you fill the vbos before the final draw.